# How many time needs a Google Play update of my app to be published?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on google play.

I updated the app to 1.0.1, and i can check it is updated on google publish website.

But in my phones and in google play the app is still on 1.0 and can't be updated.

How many time need google to publish my update on google play?

thanks

Comment: Updating new APK does not show instantly. I would get worried only after a day while usually I've seen updates present within 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved, it takes about two hours, sometimes three hours

Comment: You can see one line in your developer account "App will live after google review"

Comment: In my case, in this current date, took around 2 days. That means it varies from several hours to several days.

Comment: during corona session it is taking 6 hours to 7 days for each update to approved by google team.

Comment: I have updated my app yesterday 24 Nov with release note: "white screen solved" and also just updated it for fixing another issue today 25 Nov with release note: "sign in issue solved", however I see no changes and on mobile play store latest update date is: 24 Nov with my new release note: "sign in issue solved". also on my google play console there is no review app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your application published faster. You should publish as alpha before. Publishing as alpha is necessary for testing In App Billing and no one will see your application on alpha except your testers. When it comes to publish on production (normal publishing everyone can see this version), you should just upgrade from alpha to production and that’s it. Your application will be live on 10 minutes or less.

Answer (score 0):

Google says it may take them up to 7 days or longer to review apps submitted to the Play Store from certain developers.

[For more information click here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-store-approval-new-apps-time/)