# Upgrade app from Google Play Store, shows as "open"

Tags: android

I have the same application, but two separate builds, one build is pre-installed on my phone, the other one is uploaded to the Google Play Store. Both builds share the same exact name (com.example.ktest), the only difference is the version numbers:

Pre-installed on the phone built with:

```
versionCode 444
versionName "0.8"
```

Uploaded to playstore built with:

```
versionCode 555
versionName "1.0"
```

Now I have the pre-installed app on my phone, but the newer version which is at the app store is not installed. Now when I go to Google Play Store, the Google Play Store offers me to "open" the app, instead of "update", even though the app on the Google Play Store has a higher version number.

Why doesn't the Google Play Store offer me to "upgrade" the app? Thanks!

**Please note:** The build was uploaded on the playstore 4 days ago and it's present there, **I'm not having issues uploading the app to the store**. The issue I'm having is that it doesn't offer to "upgrade", it offers only to "open" at the playstore apps page.

Comment: It takes some time to upgrade the app in playstore.When youstarted to  upgrade the app?However most of the times it took 2-4 hours.

Comment: you need to wait for about 30m after the build is released until you receive an update

Comment: It has been 4 days since I uploaded the app to the playstore, the app is present at the store, but instead of offering to "upgrade" it offers to "open", even though the version of pre-installed app is lower than the one at the playstore..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many time needs a Google Play update of my app to be published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426664/how-many-time-needs-a-google-play-update-of-my-app-to-be-published)

Comment: Have you tried with other phones?

Comment: Try to delete app `data` and `cash` of `Play Store` on your device.

Comment: @Bek, thanks for the hint, I tried both of your suggestions, but no effect. It turns out the problem was 'unsigned' APK for the locally installed build.

Comment: @Sniffer no, it's not a possible duplicate, my question is regarding a different issue. Please remove the duplicate comment as it might be misleading to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the *pre-installed application* was not signed. After signing it, the playstore offered to "upgrade" instead of "open".

Comment: Why is this down voted? I clearly described the problem and almost all the answers were off topic and unrelated to my question. I clearly provided a solution to the exact problem described, down voting this is illogical and prevents others who face the same problem on finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have published 10 applications so far and I can tell you that there is no certain time. However most of the times it took 2-4 hours. There is one more thing, contrary to popular belief it is not an automated process. If you do something against Google Policy they may reject your application. But sometimes they don't reject even if you do something against their policy. I know this is very confusing but it is the truth.

EDIT: If you want your application published faster. You should publish as alpha before. Publishing as alpha is necessary for testing In-App Billing and no one will see your application on alpha except your testers. When it comes to publishing on production (normal publishing everyone can see this version), you should just upgrade from alpha to production and that’s it. Your application will be live on 10 minutes or less.

Comment: @0X29a Please accept the answer if it is working for you.

Comment: This answer does not answer my question and is completely off topic, did you even read it?